# Neo4j plugin @Name

Tags: neo4j

I'm confused by a detail in the Neo4j [plugin docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html).  The example `GetAll` class has two methods: one named `getAllNodes` and annotated with `@Name( "get_all_nodes" )`, and the other named `getAllRelationships` and not annotated with `@Name`.  Further down the page, it shows how these methods appear in the API discovery response:

```
"extensions" : {
  "GetAll" : {
    "get_all_nodes" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GetAll/graphdb/get_all_nodes",
    "get_all_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GetAll/graphdb/getAllRelationships"
  }
}
```

How did `getAllRelationships` acquire the name `get_all_relationships`?  Is this just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested out this one. This is **typo** in documentation.

Neo4j version - 2.3.0

Result of this example on my machine:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:7474/db/data/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 07:35:39 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 961
Server: Jetty(9.2.4.v20141103)

{
  "extensions" : {
    "GetAllNodes" : {
      "get_all_nodes" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GetAllNodes/graphdb/get_all_nodes",
      "getAllRelationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GetAllNodes/graphdb/getAllRelationships"
    }
  },
  // ...
}%
```

As we can see:

- If method has annotation, then name is acquired from annotation
- If method don't have annotation, then name is acquired from method name

And finally - [PluginPointFactoryImpl::nameOf](https://github.com/dmontag/neo4j-community/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/plugins/PluginPointFactoryImpl.java#L225) - actual method that determines name.